# Impala insert from one table to another

Tags: impala

I have a parquet format partitioned table in Hive which was inserted data using impala. Say for a partition Original table has 40 files and when i insert data into a new table which is of same structure and partition column ( INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE SELECT * FROM  ORIGINAL_TABLE). Now i am seeing 10 files for the same partition column. So my question is how to ensure same size of files maintained.

Comment: Are both tables parquet?

Comment: Yes both are parquet and same partition column.